# Facebook getSignedRequest not always grabbing page id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a Facebook app that I'd like to use as a page tab. The idea is that it would display different content based on the Facebook Page the tab is used on.

```
<?php require_once ("php-sdk/facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"]; ?>
```

Unfortunately, it only occasionally works. Right now, I'm simply trying to echo out the $page_id, and it doesn't always work. Sometimes it will correctly echo out the $page_id, other times it echoes out a null value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the code is definitely being called because of a page load on a page tab app? check the HTTP request method too, maybe you're getting GET requests (i.e if the user clicks a link inside the iframe) which don't have the signed request present

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your comment, but I'm putting that php code in the head of my file that loads inside an iframe in the tab. So I'm assuming it's being called. For what it's worth, here is the reference I used to help write the code. http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/

Comment: @rmlumley: He wanted to say that Facebook sends signed_request only once when the tab loads, not when user clicks random links inside the iframe.

Comment: @martin Makes sense, thanks. With that said, this still should work. That code is being called when the tab loads.

Comment: @rmlumley: so when you refresh Facebook tab, it sometimes works and sometimes not?

Comment: @martin Nope. It used to work for me, doesn't at all anymore. It works for a co-worker of mine. Another co-worker of mine it didn't at first, but now does. It doesn't work at all for my wife. It didn't work at all for another friend of mine.

Comment: @martin I figured it out. It was a server issue - answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out. There is nothing wrong with my code. The problem was on the server. It was set to change all http traffic to https traffic. So, the tab was pulling the page_id for individuals who set up Facebook to use https. It wasn't able to pull in the page_id if someone was viewing facebook using http.

It's all fixed now. The server allows http traffic to stay http and https traffic to stay https.

Comment: Good, didn't even think about this option. Good to know.

Comment: Great answer.  However, note that the real problem isn't that the tab can't "[pull] the page_id for individuals [who] use https".  Rather, it's that if you're using mod_rewrite or some other method to forward HTTP requests to HTTPS, the request may lose Facebook's signed_request in the process.  With this information in mind, there are actually many valid solutions (storing the signed_request in the session before forwarding, using mod_rewrite's QSA flag (might work), etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I was geting the same problem with facebook tab app on heroku, the problem was at the sample code index.php

```
if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
```

header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit();

The redirection was making page info array to desapear. Without this everything works :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, after hours surfing the internet i found out the problem was with my app secret ID

i hope this helped